# php i need null to be null, zero to be zero

Tags: php, null

my table field status is NULL[default], or it is 0, or 1. then i assign to PHP var $status. when value is NULL i want to display no icon, when value is 0, display a gray check image, when value is 1, display a green check image.

trouble is, NULL value shows a gray check image, 0 does not show a check image. somehow NULL and 0 are alike but only in one direction. what i mean is, regardless of how i conditionally test if var is null, not null, null but not zero, they get interpreted wrongly. it is confusing. there must be a simple straight foward way to keep NULL and 0 separate and distinct. i grab the value:

```
$status = $Card['status']; //from above array.
    if ($status == 1) {
        $status = '1';
    } else if ($status == 0) {
        $status = '0';
    } else if ($status === NULL) {
        $status = 'NULL';
    }
```

then to display the images either gray, green, or none at all i am trying this:

```
    if ($status == '1') {
        echo "<img src='../images/status_check_green.png' />";
    } else if ($status == '0') {
        echo "<img src='../images/porc_check_gray.png' />";
    } else if ($status == 'NULL') {
        echo "<img src='' />";
    }
}
```

i know i do not need the '' around the values, but i am trying to literalize everything to force valid comparisons. likely no need for someone to try unraveling my code; but to elucidate how to keep NULL and 0 separate. it's like i am missing something fundamental here. btw, when i stuff a js var with the PHP var, it gets the correct value; they just don't follow the comparison like i need them to.

ideas?

Comment: You could always use `===`, or check for `NULL` before checking for `0`.

Comment: `empty` & `is_null` perhaps might help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HI your issue is procedure order or not type checking the `0` ( depending if you want to catch `false` )

```
if ($status == 1) {
    $status = '1';
} else if ($status == 0) {
    $status = '0';  //<--- this runs on null because (null == 0) is true
} else if ($status === NULL) {
    $status = 'NULL'; //<--- this block is un-reachable
}
```

Because your not type checking with `===` of `0` null will return true for that condition.

See this sandbox with and example using `$status = null;`

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1f3dd9d83d0026aa0f682b61bed2ba858ae285aa

Outputs:

```
'0'
```

If you change it to this

```
if ($status == 1) {
    $status = '1';
} else if ($status === 0) {
    $status = '0';  
} else if ($status === NULL) {
    $status = 'NULL';
}
```

As you can see here using the same setting for `$status`

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d86b0c60c06338d2d6ee1c1fa9d3fa7e08a22663

Outputs

```
'NULL'
```

The other way to fix it would be to switch them so the more specific one is first.

```
if ($status == 1) {
    $status = '1';
} else if ($status === NULL) {
    $status = 'NULL';
} else if ($status == 0) {  //I would prefer if(!$status){ but I'm lazy
    $status = '0';  
}
```

Then `0` would catch `false` as well as `0` but not `null` as the block above it will catch it first.  You can see this last one here

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3028f5826dcede29b14dd8cfc03618ea5830c12c

Which also outputs

```
'NULL'
```

Cheers!

Comment: i used your first example and things working like a charm! i like the flow of checking for 1==>green check, 0==>gray check, NULL==>no check. subtle but sublime type checking so important. your response was extraordinary and thorough - thank you!!

Comment: Sure, glad I could help.